# My iOS App is crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS while trying to load certificate into GStreamer. gst_ios_init()

Tags: ios, objective-c, gstreamer, exc-bad-access

I want to update the GStreamer version of my iOS App from 1.16.3 to **1.18.6**.

The main change that I am aware of, is that now GStreamer 1.18.x only works with openssl (gnutls cannot be used anymore).

**What I did:**

I downloaded the installer from here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/ios/1.18.6/gstreamer-1.0-devel-1.18.6-ios-universal.pkg
I updated the `gst_ios_init.h` file to use openssl instead of gnutls, by replacing the `#define GST_IOS_GIO_MODULE_GNUTLS` line with `#define GST_IOS_GIO_MODULE_OPENSSL`

The App is now crashing (iOS 15.4.1) when calling the `g_tls_file_database_new (ca_certificates, NULL);` on the `gst_ios_init.m` file. I am getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception, which is weird because I didn't change the certificate location.

This is a snippet of the code where the App is crashing, it only crashes if there is a file where `ca_certificates` points to. If there isn't then the `gst_ios_init` call ends properly, but then I cannot use encryption, which I really need to!!

```
 **const gchar *resources_dir = [resources UTF8String];
    const gchar *tmp_dir = [tmp UTF8String];
    const gchar *cache_dir = [cache UTF8String];
    const gchar *docs_dir = [docs UTF8String];
    const gchar *library_dir = [libraryString UTF8String];
    gchar *ca_certificates;
        
    g_setenv ("TMP", tmp_dir, TRUE);
    g_setenv ("TEMP", tmp_dir, TRUE);
    g_setenv ("TMPDIR", tmp_dir, TRUE);
    g_setenv ("XDG_RUNTIME_DIR", resources_dir, TRUE);
    g_setenv ("XDG_CACHE_HOME", cache_dir, TRUE);
        
    g_setenv ("HOME", docs_dir, TRUE);
    g_setenv ("XDG_DATA_DIRS", resources_dir, TRUE);
    g_setenv ("XDG_CONFIG_DIRS", resources_dir, TRUE);
    g_setenv ("XDG_CONFIG_HOME", cache_dir, TRUE);
    g_setenv ("XDG_DATA_HOME", resources_dir, TRUE);
    g_setenv ("FONTCONFIG_PATH", resources_dir, TRUE);


    ca_certificates = g_build_filename (library_dir, "ca.pem", NULL);
    g_setenv ("CA_CERTIFICATES", ca_certificates, TRUE);

#if defined(GST_IOS_GIO_MODULE_OPENSSL)
  GST_G_IO_MODULE_LOAD(openssl);
#endif

  if (ca_certificates) {
    GTlsBackend *backend = g_tls_backend_get_default ();
    if (backend) {
      GTlsDatabase *db = g_tls_file_database_new (ca_certificates, NULL);
      if (db)
        g_tls_backend_set_default_database (backend, db);
    }
  }
  g_free (ca_certificates);

  gst_init (NULL, NULL);**
```

Here's also an screenshot of the crash.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCVsa.png)

Comment: There is no error message in console when it crashes?

Comment: Nothing shows on the console, but I have some info on the calls performed. (image attached) BIO_free is where it crashes.